Pitch shift not present on VLC on Mac
Im user the latest version of VLC for Mac M1 (3.0.20). I want to change the pitch of a song, and the pitch shift feature that always was on Audio Effects -> Advance, now is not there. There's no Advance tab at all.
How can I get pitch shift on Mac?

Does video - How to Change Audio Pitch while playing - Super User answer your question?

@DavidPostill - I've added an answer for Mac on that page, as VLC prefs are completely different. That can make this a true dupe now.

@Tetsujin as per the new info you added for Mac, yes it's a duplicated! yet I posted before your clarification on the other post! ;) btw do you know if I can save settings for each song? I mean on song A I keep no pitch shiftting and on song B I add pitch shifttng? Or I need to change it manually song by song at playback moment?
